# Recover data from "shading interp" command in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, surf

Suppose I have some `x, y, z` data plotted with the `surf` function:

```
xyz = [1 2 1; 2 1 2; 0 1 1; 3 2 3];
xlabels = [0 2 4];
ylabels = [0 1 2 3];
figure
surf(xlabels,ylabels,xyz)
view(2)
```

[image]

And if I run `shading interp`, I get the following:

```
figure
surf(xlabels,ylabels,xyz)
view(2)
shading interp
```

[image]
How can I recover the underlying new data structure that's produced by `shading interp`. That is, I want to have a data structure that I can query from a specific `x` and `y` index and recover the `z` value (the color)?

Comment: Do you actually want the color being shown on screen or just the interpolated value? The latter is much easier to compute using [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html).

Comment: I guess just the value is sufficient, because then I would put those values again back into another surf function and it would handle the coloring.